# Java: For loop on Objects of Strings

Tags: java, string, list, for-loop, iteration

I'm new in Java and I have to solve this exercise. I have this code:

```
    public class StringList { 
        private String list = "";
        public StringList(String... str) { 
            for (String s : str) list += s+"\t"; 
        }
    }
```

and I have to change the class so that its objects allow the iteration by using this instruction:

```
for (String s : new StringList("a", "b", "c")) System.out.println(s);
```

My idea was to create a List and iterate on it. So I changed the code in this way:

```
public class StringList { 
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public StringList(String... str) {
        for (String s: str) list.add(s);
    }
}
```

but when I try the iteration with the above instruction I get this error (*Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable*) and I spent hours trying to fix it but I keep failing. Any help?

Comment: Please use Iterator.....

Comment: try google it first. (https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/iterator/java-lang-iterable-interface-example/)

Comment: `StringList` should implement `Iterable<String>`.

Comment: why does everyone have started thinking that this is a tutoronline site?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [`Iterable<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) to your `StringList` like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class StringList implements Iterable<String> {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public StringList(String... str) {
        for (String s: str) { list.add(s); }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super String> action) {
        list.forEach(action);
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<String> spliterator() {
        return list.spliterator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it the clean way, give a look at the java.lang.Iterable interface : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

If your StringList class implements it, then the instruction will work. I'll let you complete the exercise yourself though, but you can start with

```
public class StringList implements Iterable<String> {
    // the attribute you need to store the strings object

    // your constructor

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        // This is what you need to fill
    }
}
```

PS : Using a list of string as an attribute is not a bad idea at all and will save you a lot of efforts and time, search what you can do with it